# Activity Duration Per Task within specified hours

Tags: workflow-activity

I use the OOB 3 state workflow and the Activity Duration Report to calculate the length of time a list item stays in each state. The OOB duration includes non-business hours. Can I set the time range the workflow tracks?

*Note: I'm working with SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

No matter if workflow is build as Sequential or State machine, it consists of activities that are executed **one at a time**. Activities have 6 [states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628512.aspx):

1. Initialized
2. Executing
3. Canceling
4. Closed
5. Compensating
6. Faulting

When activity enters `Executing` state, it can end up in one of `Closed`, `Canceling` or `Faulting`. **Cancellation & Error Report** covers workflows that contain activity that ended up in the last two, while **Activity Duration Report** gives information about workflows that managed to end successfully (all activities went from `Executing` to `Closed`).

So basically we only know an exact moments when each activity started (T1) and when it finished (T2), then simple `T2 - T1` is put into ADR.

That's why the Activity Duration Report is not customizable the way you want, sorry.